# Regarding mootools and jQuery demo

Tags: jquery, mootools, sample, demo

i found http://visualjquery.com/ more useful when i was learning jQuery with each function explained in demo along with code sample in a practical manner.

im looking for the same in mootools. is anyone find any website which provide demos and sample coding like above the same in visualjquery.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick and Tim mentioned, the best resource is the documentation, but to make stuff more interactive, you can play around with the code within jsFiddle's context - example: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/c6n7q/

Comment: Thanxs oscar ,

here u go one more from mootools http://mootools.net/shell/mAWcm/

Comment: Yes, I'm the co-author of both :-)

Answer (score 1):

The offical mootools page (http://mootools.net/docs/core) should be fine. Every function is listed with an exampled just like on visualjquery.com.

Answer (score 1):

The MooTools API has samples within it like [jQuery does](http://api.jquery.com/).

[You can get started with it here](http://mootools.net/docs/core).